# Jquery and AJAX - escape from click event

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

It's a rails app. I have a browser of items grouped in four categories. At the top of browser there are links for those categories. If you click (if the ajax request is submitted) box called `#index_przedmioty` is replaced by `#loader`, and if ajax request is finished `#loader` hides and site renders items from another category.

My problem is that there are buttons that adds these items to let's say 'basket' it's also made through ajax. So I want `.ajaxStart` and `.ajaxStop` to be executed only after click on `#wykindex_head a` links. Another words is there any way to escape `click()` event?

Directly after reloading page, before `click()`, items are added to 'basket' without reloading with `#loader` stuff - just as I want. After i submit first `click()` on adding item to basket the whole bucket `#index_przedmioty` reloads which is not what I want.

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $('#wykindex_head a').click(function() {
      $('#loader').ajaxStart(function() {
          $(this).parent().find('#index_przedmioty').hide();
          $(this).show();
      }).ajaxStop(function(){
          $(this).hide();
          $(this).parent().find('#index_przedmioty').show();
      });
    });
```

});

I have read about one solution - setting `$.ajax({ global: false });` and I made it in application.js, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I think your question is not clear enough.